# Where to write business logic with AWS Amplify/AppSync

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm considering using Amplify for a new project, but struggling to wrap my head around this.

Let's just say I have a product like Facebook Groups. A Group has an owner and also a list of members.

I want my mutation resolvers to add additional checks, for example:

- When I create a Group, add the owner to the list of members (or alternatively, when I create a Group, fail if the owner is not in the list of members)
- When I update the list of members in a Group, fail if I attempt to remove the owner of the Group

Where the right place to express this kind of logic? I don't want it on the client and was expecting to find some sort of way to add a lambda to be run as part of a resolver, but so far haven't found it!

Answer (score 1):

Oh, pretty sure this is exactly what I want: https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#function

Will test and accept if I'm right...

Comment: Seems like the way to go...did this work for you?